# Open camera application android

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a project with the theme "Navigation Drawer Activity" and I would like to have two options on the left menu :

- Open the device camera to take pictures
- Open the photo gallery

Here is a part of the code :

`

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
```

`if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}`

I tried several things but none of them opened the device camera.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starting inbuilt camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                                                
startActivityForResult(intent, PIC_CAPTURED);
```

For opening gallery to select picture

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                  "Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

Comment: Thank you ! But what is PIC_CAPTURED and RESULT_LOAD_IMG ?

Comment: They are any constants just add private int PIC_CAPTURED = 1 and private int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 2

Comment: And don't forget to accept the answer if it worked :)

Comment: those are not simply constants. those are request code. dont confuse people @ShashankUdupa

Answer (score 0):

For starting camera intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0); // 0 is the request code
```

For receiving the result image

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {  //checking if its for our sent request
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) { //checking if the intent sent result successfully
    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); //converting camera intent result to bitmap image
   } 
   }
  }
```

How to open gallery

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select   Picture"),1111); //1111 is request code
```

Why request code :

It is used so that when result is received from that intent we can match that it is sent from which intent. Just like a flag for testing. you can see the use in my example code above when receiving data from camera and setting to Bitmap. Its not that you need to add 0 or 1111. You can put any integer value